# Force a link to open in Safari instead of the in-app browser

Tags: iphone, safari

I have an issue with QR Readers. I encode a URL within a QR Code. When read by many iPhone App they will open the URL within a WebView within the app.

I want to open a vCard there, which those internal things just won't do - page stays blank but when opened directly in Safari everything works great.

Here is my example:

- If you visit [vcard.nikb.de](http://vcard.nikb.de) in Safari it will bring up a VCard
- If you scan the [QR](http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=vcard.nikb.de&size=250x250) below (which opens the site mentioned) it won't open...

[image]

So my question is: Is there any way to get out of the WebView and open Safari?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, unless the app was designed to explicitly support opening Safari (with a button for instance).  You can't modify an app's internal messaging to its own webviews on stock OS iOS devices, for app security reasons if nothing else.

Comment: I suggest contacting the developer about adding this functionality.

Comment: DO you see any possibility make IOS view the VCard from the WebView?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try www.qrstuff.com
2. Choose "contact details (vcard)" in the left column. Put in your data and try that QR-code. Shouldn't need to open Safari for that.

Note: Don't miss the last option, after all the inputs, to link to a vcf-file or input the vcf-data into the qr code as-is. The second option works fine for me.

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Hi - thanks a lot for your answer and your suggestion.

Using a URL QR was a well considerd decision.
The resulting Matrix is a lot smaller than one with the whole contact details included. Not only a smaller QR is easier to read for smartphones but also it looks better when printed.

Also the vcfQR wont give me the possibility to store a picture in it does it?